# Why does test takes longer than training?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I'am training sklearn `KNNClassifier` on MNIST digits dataset.

Here is the code :

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()

start_time = time.time()
print (start_time)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

print (elapsed_time)
```

it takes 40s. However, when I test on test data, it takes more than a few minutes (still running), while there are 6 times less test data than train data.

Here is the code  :

```
y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
```

Could you explain me why it takes so much time (more time than training) ? Something to solve this ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why  do you expect them to take the same time? These are different functions and consequently their running times will differ regardless of the data. It's one thing to train a model and another thing to classify using it.

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy Training data are used to build the classifier so it takes computational time (while testing data are used when the model already is built). Moreover, there are six times more training data than test ones so I can not see any reason why it should last so long

Comment: I am not exactly sure of the specific implementation of the function but in the case of KNN, it makes sense for the prediction to take more time than the building the model since the model needs to measure the euclidean(or other type of distance) for each sample in the test data with its k nearest neighbors while it doesn't need to do this in the training.

Comment: To reduce the test time, consider tuning the "K" parameter or choosing another model altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about the working of the k-NN algorithm. It is a classic example of lazy learning, where at prediction time the distances to the original training data have to be calculated (to decide which are its closest neigbours).
At training time, it doesn't need to do very expensive distance calculation.

So the difference is mostly about going from `.fit()` to `.predict()`
When you would actually try to predict the train-set, this would take even longer.

For more information, see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_learning)

For solutions: think about whether this algorithm is actually ideal for your case, or if you could do with cruder approximation of the distance.